# Duvida no erro .map is not a function

Tags: react

Criei uma tabela com 5 dropdowns, cada uma recebendo seu conteudo de uma api. Porém as vezes quando a pagina recarrega eu recebo o erro "filterL" is not a function,no caso acontece com qualquer um dos .map que eu criei mas não entendi pq está dando esse erro. Podem me ajudar a entender? Sou novo no react

Os dados que estou retornando para dentro das dropdowns estão dessa forma por exemplo, em json:

```
[
{
Cdgrupo: 1,
Grupos: "VIDROS"
},
{
Cdgrupo: 2,
Grupos: "PVC"
},
{
Cdgrupo: 3,
Grupos: "ACESS VIDRO"
},
]
```

Segue meu código:

```
class App extends Component{



  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        Produtos:[],
        Grupos:[],
        SubGrupos:[],
        Fabricantes:[],
        Linhas: [],
        ValorProd:'',
        ValorGP:'',
        ValorL: '',
        ValorFB:'',
        ValorSB:'',
        dados:[],
    };

}


componentDidMount() {
  Promise.all([

  fetch('http://localhost:8081/xxx/xxx/TCadastros/GetListaProdutos/'), 
  fetch('http://localhost:8081/xxx/xxx/TCadastros/GetListaGrupos/'),
  fetch('http://localhost:8081/xxx/xxx/TCadastros/GetListaSubGrupos/'),
  fetch('http://localhost:8081/xxx/xxx/TCadastros/GetListaFabricantes/'),
  fetch('http://localhost:8081/xxx/xxxx/TCadastros/GetListaLinhas/')

])

    .then(([res1, res2, res3, res4, res5]) => { 
       return Promise.all([res1.json(), res2.json(), res3.json(), res4.json(), res5.json()]) 
       })

    .then(([res1, res2, res3, res4, res5]) => {
      this.setState({Produtos:res1, Grupos:res2, SubGrupos:res3, Fabricantes:res4, Linhas:res5})

      /*console.log("Produtos: " ,res1, "Grupos: " ,res2,"SubGrupos: " ,res3, "Fabricantes: " ,res4, "Linhas: ", res5,)*/
    });
}



  render(){



      //Montagem das informações vindas do banco dentro das combos.

    let grupo1 = this.state.Grupos
    let filterGP = grupo1.map((Grupos) =>
                <option key={Grupos.Cdgrupo} >{Grupos.Grupos}</option>);


    let filterSB = this.state.SubGrupos
    let prodsSub = filterSB.map((SubGrupos) =>
                <option key={SubGrupos.CdSubGrupo}>{SubGrupos.SubGrupo}</option>
    );

    let filterL = this.state.Linhas
    let prodsL = filterL.map((Linhas) =>
                <option key={Linhas.Cdlinha}>{Linhas.Linha}</option>
    );

   let filterFab = this.state.Fabricantes
   let prodsFB = filterFab.map((Fabricantes) =>
                <option key={Fabricantes.Cdfabricante}>{Fabricantes.Fabricante}</option>


    );


  return (
    <div className="App-header">



        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <div className="containerPrincipal">

          <button type="submit" className='btn-buscar btn btn-success'>Filtrar</button>


          <Input type='select' className="comboGP" style={{minWidth:"220px", width:"220px", maxWidth:"220px"}}onClick={this.handleSelectChangeGP}>
          <option value=""  >Selecione um Grupo</option>
          {filterGP}
          </Input>

          <Input type='select' className="comboSB" style={{width:"380px", minWidth:"380px",maxWidth:"380px" }} onClick={this.handleSelectChangeSB}>
          <option  value=''  >Selecione um SubGrupo</option>
          {prodsSub}
          </Input>

          <Input type='select' className="comboL" style={{width:"220px", minWidth:"220px", maxWidth:"220px"}} onClick={this.handleSelectChangeL}>
          <option  value=''  >Selecione uma Linha</option>
          {prodsL}
  </Input>

          <Input  type='select' className="comboFB"  style={{width:"450px", minWidth:"450px", maxWidth:"450px"}} onClick={this.handleSelectChangeFB} >
          <option  value=''  >Selecione um Fabicante</option>
          {prodsFB}
          </Input>

      </div>
        <table className="container-table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th className='head'>Código</th>
              <th className='head'>Produto</th>
              <th className='head'>Fabricante</th>
              <th className='head'>Grupo</th>
              <th className='head'>SubGrupo</th>
              <th className='head'>Linha</th>
              <th className='head'>Preço</th>

            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {dados.length ?
              dados.map(dados => (
            <tr>
              <td>{dados.Cdproduto}</td>
              <td>{dados.Produto}</td>
              <td>{dados.Fabricante}</td>
              <td>{dados.Grupo}</td>
              <td>{dados.SubGrupo}</td>
              <td>{dados.Linha}</td>
              <td>{dados.Preco}</td>

            </tr>
              ))
              :
            (<tr>
              <td>-</td>
              <td>-</td>
              <td>-</td>
              <td>-</td>
              <td>-</td>
              <td>-</td>
              <td>-</td>
             </tr>)
              }
          </tbody>
        </table>

        </form>


      </div>  
  );
}
}
export default App;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Talvez porque a requisição leva um pouco mais de tempo e o código é executado antes do estado ser setado? Sugiro remover todo o código irrelevante para a pergunta, mantenha apenas as requisições e os `map` para deixar a pergunta mais compacta, simples e entendível

Comment: @Costamilam Obrigado pela dica, retirei o que julguei desnecessario mostrar no código.Quanto a sua resposta, não entendi muito bem, pode me explicar melhor?

Comment: O que o @Costamilam quiz dizer é que a promessa (promise) não recebeu o que foi prometido a tempo... daí o objeto ou array não foi definido, ele não consegue mapear os dados... e por isso o método quebra, e diz que não existe o tal método. No backend você tem que trazer um array vazio, quando não tiver dado, não esqueça disso...

Answer (score 1):

Gabriel, o que pode estar acontecendo é que a resposta não esteja vindo como um array. Veja que o console te apresenta um erro de tipo, ou seja, você não recebeu um array e sim outra coisa.

Você tem a opção de, ao dar o setState colocar a resposta dentro do array, tipo,
`this.setState({ Linhas: [...res5] })` ou verifique primeiro se a resposta vem como array mesmo.

Comment: Usando o console.log o que eu estou retornando vem no formato [ { json } ], creio eu que no caso eu estou retornando um objeto em vez de um array, correto?

Comment: Possivelmente, Gabriel. Mas o formato de dados que vem do Backend é sempre bom vir por JSON mesmo.

Comment: Entendi. O que está me deixando mais confuso é que na maioria das vezes ele funciona normal, digamos que a cada 5 vezes que eu dou reload na pagina e a requisição é feita só 1 ou 2 que ele me retorna esse erro, as outras vezes ele recebe os dados normal e funciona tudo ok.